# How does blender calculate the solve error in camera tracking?

Tags: tracking

Just curious, how or what algorithm does blender use to calculate the solve error in camera tracking. A quantitative explanation would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender currently uses a KLT-Tracker [(Kanade–Lucas–Tomasi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanade%E2%80%93Lucas%E2%80%93Tomasi_feature_tracker) which is documented [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/index.html).

For the calculation of the solve error the documentation of this [implementation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/vision/ref/vision.pointtracker-class.html) might be interesting.