# Which Algorithm use Blender for Motion Tracking in version 2.79?

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor, documentation

We are using Blender for Multimodal Analysis, the Motion Tracking Module is ideal for our Workflow and we are very happy with the options and functionality of the Tracker.

In order to describe the use of Blender in our workflow for scientific papers I need to know some details about the used tracking algorithms.

I have found that the version 2.6 uses the KLT (Kanade-Lukas-Tomasi) algorithm and the CAD algorithm in the [documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:DE/2.6/Manual/Motion_Tracking#KLT_tracker_options) and in [another question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15611/how-does-blender-calculate-the-solve-error-in-camera-tracking) in Stack Exchange .

In the current manual I see [some references](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/clip/editing/track.html) pointing to version 2.63 or 2.64 .

Does version 2.79 use the same trackers as the version 2.6? If there are changes (or not), can anyone tell me where I can find details (manual, documentation, source code) about the tracking algorithm used in the current version (2.79)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The library is called *libmv*: https://developer.blender.org/tag/libmv/ (old google project)